# How to associate .pyw file and idle.bat file with assoc and ftype command

Tags: python-3.x, windows, batch-file, cmd, command

I gave it a try as follows.

[image]

and I write ftype as follows.
[image]

I thought I could execute .pyw file as memorandom application.
But the result is different.

So I searched original associations by FIND command.

[image]

I also use %L instead of %1, but the result is not changed.
Python.ArchiveFile is set automatically, not by myself.
So I can trust this way. I use double quote and argument "%*", but the
result is not changed.

---

After the survey, I have found these things.

```
assoc .pyw = PYTHONW.EXE

ftype PYTHONW.EXE = "C:\Users\****\AppData\Local\Python\Python310\Lib\idlelib\idle.bat" "%1" "%*"
```

PYTHON.EXE is a variable we can define it by ourselves.
Now, I associate .pyw extension file with PYTHON.EXE
And, ftype can connect the variable to concrete executable application file.

I followed achipfl's suggestion. But the result is like this.

[image]

I hear that %1 is a commandline argument for getting a file name.
%* is also an argument like *args.

I indicated the exact path of idle.bat, but name of the file directory is embedded as just a candidate for application.Moreover, I cannot execute my .pyw file by this.

Assoc and ftype command is for my purpose without doubt. What is wrong with my command?

---

**Old**

I want to associate .pyw file and idle.bat command.

Now, if I double-click my .pyw file, the file is executed, a GUI shows up,

because it is executed from pythonw.exe.

I want to execute it from idle.bat.

By mouse, I can do this easily.

But how can I do the same thing by command prompt?

I searched the way on the web, I found that assoc & ftype command did it.

But the both commands don't go well.

How do I write command?

assoc .pyw=idle.bat

Do you know how to do it?

Comment: `assoc .pyw=pywfile` and `ftype pywfile="D:\Full\Path\To\idle.bat" %*`?

Comment: @aschipfl I tried your suggestion, but it doesn't meet my demand.

Comment: What @aschipfl wrote is the correct way to get your *demand*. If it doesn't meet your *demand*, then what you *demand* is different than what you've written in your question.

Comment: @Ken White Sorry for that, you are right. But it doesn't work well. Should I delete %1 as ashipfl wrote.

Comment: You could play around with the argument portion: use `%1` instead of `%*`, or put quotes around…

Comment: @aschipfl Could you associate by your suggestion?

Comment: No, but I don't want to destroy its current association. Anyway, `ftype pywfile="D:\Full\Path\To\idle.bat" "%1" %*` should do it (optionally removing the `%*` part), given that you've got administrative privileges…